# SilverStripe 3.1.x - Extend lostpassword form to include captcha

Tags: forms, captcha, silverstripe

Whats the best/correct way to extend/modify the LostPasswordForm in SilverStripe 3.1.x to include recaptcha?  Another security issue, which was classified as medium risk.  Here's what they say:

> **Observation:** The Forgot Password functionality can be used to spam the
>   email address of an admin user.
>
> **Sample Affected URL:**
>   http://example.com/Security/LostPasswordForm
>
> **Impact:** A malicious user may use a bot or an automated method to
>   repeatedly submit a Forgot Password request. The email inbox could be
>   rendered inaccessible or useless due to the large number of messages.

[image: Defect - Request Replay]

> **Recommendation:** Implement a one time use challenge-response test such
>   as a CAPTCHA during the Forgot Password request to prevent automated
>   bots or to slow down humans who attempt to flood the user's email
>   inboxes. This CAPTCHA functionality should expire after one use.

As time is of the essence here, any pointers (or even a complete solution) would be greatly appreciated.  It would be easy to implement hacking away at the core, but it's not best-practice.  Can someone share how it should be done by properly extending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think overriding the default template is the way to go,
but you should be able to use a custom class extending `MemberLoginForm` rather than altering the core file...

_config.php

```
Object::useCustomClass('MemberLoginForm', 'MyExtendedMemberLoginForm');
```

MyExtendedMemberLoginForm.php

```
class MyExtendedMemberLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm {
  //override methods, add your fields...
}
```